# Теги с нижним подчеркиванием

Tags: обсуждение, метки, замена-меток

Предлагаю:

**Программа-минимум:** удалить дубли, как здесь: [[виртуальная-машина](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0/info)], [[виртуальная_машина]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0/info)

**Программа-максимум:** избавиться от тегов с нижним подчеркиванием и перейти к дефису как на оригинальном StackOverflow.

Comment: Пользуясь случаем, ещё раз пропиарю фичу "[Синонимы меток](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms)" ([обсуждение](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/68/%D0%94%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0)).

Comment: Не знаю, баг это или фича, но синонимы в таком случае создать не удается. Движок считает их за одну и ту же метку.

Comment: @Nofate, это баг потому что на фронтенде они отображаются как разные

Comment: @fori1ton а как "предложить" новый синоним?

Comment: @AntonioK, Переходишь [сюда](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms "Раздел 'синонимизации'"), выбираешь метку и предлагаешь синоним. Если позволяет репутация и рейтинг.

Comment: @AntonioK, если репутации не хватает, можно предлагать новые синонимы вопросом на Мете - кто-нибудь добавит.

Comment: Ссылка на запрос всех меток с подчёркиванием: http://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/419117/tags-with-underscore

Answer (score 2):

Вычистил метку с подчеркиванием из всех вопросов. Через сутки Дух сообщества изгонит ее в иные планы существования и мир сможет вздохнуть спокойно.

Кроме того, в будущем движок не позволит создать эту метку с подчеркиванием, пока есть вариант с дефисом.

Вероятно, такие метки появились на движке Хэшкода, который позволял и различал метки с дефисом и подчеркиванием. Сейчас они существуют одновременно, но если поискать вопросы с [виртуальная-машина](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%82%d1%83%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0), то [показываются исключительно вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0) с [виртуальная-машина](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%82%d1%83%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0).

Программа-максимум хороша, надо бы найти способ искать `_` в метках. Вручную 87 страниц сложновато перебирать.